Formal definition of an animal
The Wikipedia entry for animal defines it as a “multicellular eukaryotic organism in the biological kingdom, Animalia”. I do not find this definition very clear. In particular, it seems almost circular, as if an animal is anything we define to be an animal.
I tried finding a different definition, but the Oxford dictionary definition doesn’t seem to me to be any more satisfactory:

“a living organism that feeds on organic matter, typically having specialized sense organs and nervous system and able to respond rapidly to stimuli”

Certain plants such as Venus fly trap would seem to me to fall under this definition.
So, is there a formally accepted definition of an animal in biology? If it is the definition given by Wikipedia, how do we decide which organisms fall into this kingdom? Or is it just that whatever morally feels like an animal (e.g. human, cat, dog, horse, fish, etc.) gets put into this kingdom?

Related Q&A: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/113386/what-is-a-fungus-formally/

@virolino From the perspective of biology, reptiles are always animals. Insects are always animals.

@virolino I'm honestly curious: what contexts are you thinking of where reptiles or insects wouldn't be described as animals? I legitimately can't think of any.

The Venus Fly Trap doesn't have a nervous system.

@Idran: In the context of the real world, where jokes like this are funny exactly because of that: "Is a bat an animal or a bird?"

@virolino Huh. I guess I can see that, but to me the humor in jokes like that is specifically from the two options not being mutually exclusive and/or the mixup in wording for one of them (a.k.a., accidentally saying "animal" instead of "mammal" because they sound similar). Like, it wouldn't be funny to me if in the context of the joke birds actually weren't considered a subcategory of animals, because there wouldn't be any twist.

There are two implicit parts to the question:

what animals are as a taxon and
why we call this taxon "animals" (= Animalia = Metazoa).

Organisms are classified mostly based on the understanding of the evolutionary relationships between them. Nowadays, evolutionary relationships for extant organisms are resolved using molecular data, in particular multiple gene sequences which provide many simple characters for phylogenetic reconstructions.
There are many branches on the tree of life (clades), each one has the potential to be treated as a taxon. To understand what clade deserves a name and corresponds to a particular rank, taxonomists search for well-supported clades with easily recognizable derived traits associated with them.
So, animals can be defined as the organisms belonging to the clade that includes organisms from Trichoplax and sponges to humans, or in other words: which includes the last common ancestor of these organisms and all its descendants. It is a well-supported deep clade and we call it Animalia = Metazoa based on the fact that most organisms that have been included in the typological definitions (i.e. definitions based on formal morphological inclusion criteria) of the traditional taxon "Animalia" starting from Linnaeus belong here. The typological taxon "Animalia" in turn is an improvement upon the earlier typological definitions of the word "animals/ζῷα/animalia" starting from Aristotle and both are attempts at formalizing the intuition languages originally have for the word "animals".
Thanks to shared ancestry, animals have a number of synapomorphies (features evolved in their last common ancestor) which include multicellularity, anisogamy, specific developmental signalling pathways, reduced mitochondrial genome and others. Synapomorphies are not inclusion criteria as in typology. Even if some other group developed a similar trait (e.g. multicellularity evolved several times among eukaryotes independently) or even if some animals lose some of these traits (although outside of zoological taxonomy, one extreme case might be transmissible cancers, such as canine transmissible venereal tumour which are essentially unicellular parasites recently derived from multicellular animals) those organisms do not become/stop being animals.
Oxford Dictionary in your citation does not define what an animal is. From the perspective of modern biology, it only mentions some traits found in some animals — not all animals have nervous system and not all rapidly respond to stimuli. Analogously, organisms that independently evolved fast responses do not become animals: they do not share ancestry with them and they lack their synapomorphies. Whatever similarities they might have with animals would be due to plesiomorphies (traits inherited from a more distant ancestors) or convergences/homoplasies (traits evolved independently).

So transmissible cancers fall under kingdom of animalia?

They are self-sustaining cell lines which diverged relatively recently (hundreds to thousands of years ago), so they are outside of zoological taxonomy and nomenclature, although I imagine that if a transmissible cancer is discovered to have survived for longer periods of time over, say, 1my, this would definitively warrant establishment of a separate species. The point here though is that these cell lines do not cease to be animal cells just because they underwent reductive evolution and complete their life-cycle without a multi-cellular stage.

Good answer, +1. But to emphasize a point - which is implicit in your answer - we didn't start from the bottom of the tree of life; we started with what is 'obviously animals', like cows, and then worked our way down, so to speak. Thus, what fundamentally defines what an animal is, derives from this process, and is incidentally somewhat muddled at the bottom level.

While the information shared by @alephreish is fascinating, it does seem to fall short of answering the question "what is the defintion of an animal". It seems a bit circular: an animal is an organism that belongs to the clade Animalia. OK, but why does it belong there? Yes, the evolutionary relationships are mentioned, but where along the trail backwards do life forms become "animal" and upon what basis?

@j4nd3r53n Good point, I'll update my answer

@DaveWelden When you get to the common ancestor of all animals. "Animal" is a label for a branch of the tree of organisms, defined by common descent. A different tree of life from some alien world would not ever have an "Animal" by that definition; you might describe something as animal-like, but there is no generic "Animal" definition the way the term is used in modern biology, and it's a mistake to expect one.

You can come up with characteristics that help you identify something as an animal, but that's not the same as a definition. Something that met all the characteristics but wasn't evolved from animals would not be an animal.

No disagreements, but here is the nub: why at a certain branch did organisms become classified as Animal? Why is that common ancestor of animals THE common ancestor? That seems to be the key unanswered question.

@DaveWelden & j4nd3r53n Pls see my update to the answer, I hope it addresses your points.

@DaveWelden - "Why is that common ancestor of animals THE common ancestor?"  It's not the most recent common ancestor of "all traditional animals" who ended up representing Animalia.  It's an earlier common ancestor on that branch, one selected so as to be easier to define genetically (or phenotypically), but still not needlessly extensive beyond traditional animals.

@DaveWelden That's also fairly arbitrary. If we drew the line somewhere more recent than sponges, then we'd need a separate category for sponges all alone. We didn't, so those are animals, too.

Maybe the common ancestor is not the right way to approach this, but I feel we are getting closer. Let me approach the question this way. What were the factors that indicated branch Animalia as a separate branch/clave from the other branchs/claves? Something identifies Animalia as distinct from the others. Is it some distinctions in the DNA or RNA as mentioned in some commentary? Is it morphology? Is it generating food vs. need to obtain food externally? A combination of these and other factors?

@DaveWelden They are multicellular eukaryotes that consume (rather than produce, as plants) organic material, move, and develop through a blastula. But...that's not a definition, because if you find another multicellular eukaryote that consumes and moves, etc, that wouldn't make it an animal in the taxonomic sense. Rather, those are the hints that the group of organisms sharing those characteristics are possibly related by common descent.

So the best conclusion I can draw at this point is that it is somewhat arbitrary. Animalia includes the organisms that have historically been identified as animals as well as some that perhaps were unknown/not considered historically. But while they are related in terms of descent from a common ancestor, the selection of the ancestor and the factors that led to Animalia as a distinct branch are somewhat arbitrary. We decided to draw the line here and called it Animalia.

@DaveWelden I think that's a good summary, yes. I think it's also worth considering the broader context of the task of organizing the known life on earth, which has been quite a difficult and sometimes controversial task. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_of_life_(biology) might be a good place to start reading. I'd also suggest looking at the history of "protists" to see how organisms that may have some apparent shared characteristics are not treated as a meaningful grouping by modern biology. Conceptually, the same thing could have happened with old ideas of what makes an animal.

Certainly the task is immense and the classification schemes have evolved over time. There has been controversy and new categories have been created as knowledge has expanded. I was hoping that where the lines were drawn to say this organism is Plant, that one is Animal, the other is Fungi, etc., would be more easily explained, but perhaps it oversimplifies the reality.

@DaveWelden welcome to biology, nature does not care about our human need to group organsims in boxes. Any line we draw between organsms is at some level arbitrary.
